# Customizing the Labels of a Multienum Display

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicolumn, multicol

This question is a follow-up to [Pairing Items for Display in Two Columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640053/pairing-items-for-display-in-two-columns)

I have the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multienum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxx{This is the first sentence.}{This is the second sentence.}
\mitemxx{This is the third sentence.}{And this is the fourth sentence.}
\mitemxx{This is the fifth sentence.}{This is the last sentence in the MWE code.}
\end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

How may I (i) remove the labels 1., 2., ... , 6.? (I know with `enumitem` this is possible by `\item[]`) but that doesn't work here. Also, (ii) how could I modify the labels to something else, say, I., II., ... III.?

Comment: Why don't you use the `tasks` package?

Comment: Why don't you use just ... tables?

Comment: @Bernard Because I am not familiar with the `tasks` package. As I indicated in posting the question, I would like to extend the (helpful) answer provided in the linked post. If the objectives of both of these posts can be accomplished in a smoother fashion with `tasks` than `multienum`, perhaps you might post an answer.

Comment: @MS-SPO My experience with using tables has always resulted in code more complicated than the code(s) given in both this post and the linked post. If there is a simple way to accomplish the tasks --- perhaps you might post a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get Roman numbering use

```
\renewcommand{\regularlisti}{\setcounter{multienumi}{0}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\addtocounter{multienumi}{1}\Roman{multienumi}.}}
```

To suppress the items numbering insert

```
\renewcommand{\regularlisti}{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{}}
```

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multienum}  

\renewcommand{\regularlisti}{\setcounter{multienumi}{0}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\addtocounter{multienumi}{1}\Roman{multienumi}.}}
    
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{multienumerate}
    \mitemxx{This is the first sentence.}{This is the second sentence.}
    \mitemxx{This is the third sentence.}{And this is the fourth sentence.}
    \mitemxx{This is the fifth sentence.}{This is the last sentence in the MWE code.}
\end{multienumerate}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\regularlisti}{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{}}
    
\begin{multienumerate}
    \mitemxx{This is the first sentence.}{This is the second sentence.}
    \mitemxx{This is the third sentence.}{And this is the fourth sentence.}
    \mitemxx{This is the fifth sentence.}{This is the last sentence in the MWE code.}
\end{multienumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Simon Dispa

Answer (score 3):

With the `task` package you can do this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[label-width=4ex](2)%
\task This is the first sentence.
\task This is the second sentence.
\task This is the third sentence.
\task And this is the fourth sentence.
\task This is the fifth sentence.
\task This is the last sentence in the MWE code.
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[label=(\roman*),label-width=4ex,item-indent=3em](2)%
\task This is the first sentence.
\task This is the second sentence.
\task This is the third sentence.
\task And this is the fourth sentence.
\task This is the fifth sentence.
\task This is the last sentence in the MWE code.
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[label=\Roman*.,label-width=4ex,item-indent=3em](2)%
\task This is the first sentence.
\task This is the second sentence.
\task This is the third sentence.
\task And this is the fourth sentence.
\task This is the fifth sentence.
\task This is the last sentence in the MWE code.
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[label=(\arabic*),label-width=4ex,item-indent=3em](2)%
\task This is the first sentence.
\task This is the second sentence.
\task This is the third sentence.
\task And this is the fourth sentence.
\task This is the fifth sentence.
\task This is the last sentence in the MWE code.
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[label,label-width=4ex,item-indent=3em](2)%
\task This is the first sentence.
\task This is the second sentence.
\task This is the third sentence.
\task And this is the fourth sentence.
\task This is the fifth sentence.
\task This is the last sentence in the MWE code.
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how may one eliminate the labels? I don't see that in your output.

Comment: @jean-marie  I added this feature.

Comment: Thank you kindly @kabenyuk

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to satisfy both queries with `tasks`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multienum}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tasks}[label=\relax, label-offset=0.5em](2)
\task This is the first sentence.
\task This is the second sentence
\task This is the third sentence.
\task And this is the fourth sentence.
\task This is the fifth sentence.
\task This is the last sentence in the MWE code.
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[label=\Roman*), label-offset=0.5em](2)
\task This is the first sentence.
\task This is the second sentence
\task This is the third sentence.
\task And this is the fourth sentence.
\task This is the fifth sentence.
\task This is the last sentence in the MWE code.
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this post.

Comment: You're welcome! Always glad when I can help.